# Javascript Datepicker - disabling future dates

Tags: javascript, html, function, date, datepicker

**Just a little bit of a disclaimer: I'm pretty much a noob at JavaScript and followed a bit of a guide for my datepicker. Please go easy on me.**

I have developed a form (with my knowledge) and I have implemented a custom developed JavaScript datepicker for my 'date of incident' field.

For this field I have gotten the date to work but I need to code the datepicker so that the user cannot select any date after the currant date, only previous dates before the currant date and should also accept the currant date.

I am thinking if I could use 'minDate' or 'maxDate'? (If that's possible without jQuery)

Please note I am only using JavaScript and not jQuery or Bootstrap.

Here is the HTML and JavaScript for my datepicker code, I am not sure whether to create a new function or implement it in my currant one (It's a lot of code)

HTML:

```
<label>Date of Incident:</label><input id="datepick" placeholder="Enter the date of incident" type="text"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var datepickr = (function() {
var datepickrs = [],
currentDate = new Date(),
date = {
    current: {
        year: function() {
            return currentDate.getFullYear();
        },
        month: {
            integer: function() {
                return currentDate.getMonth();
            },
            string: function(full, months) {
                var date = currentDate.getMonth();
                return monthToStr(date, full, months);
                minDate: currentDate;
            }
        },
        day: function() {
            return currentDate.getDate();           
        }
    },
    month: {
        string: function(full, currentMonthView, months) {
            var date = currentMonthView;
            return monthToStr(date, full, months);
        },
        numDays: function(currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
            /* checks to see if february is a leap year otherwise return the respective # of days */
            return (currentMonthView == 1 && !(currentYearView & 3) && (currentYearView % 1e2 || !(currentYearView % 4e2))) ? 29 : daysInMonth[currentMonthView];
        }
    }
},
daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
buildCache = [],
handlers = {
    calendarClick: function(e) {
        if(e.target.className) {
            switch(e.target.className) {
                case 'prev-month':
                case 'prevMonth':
                    this.currentMonthView--;
                    if(this.currentMonthView < 0) {
                        this.currentYearView--;
                        this.currentMonthView = 11;
                    }
                    rebuildCalendar.call(this);
                break;
                case 'next-month':
                case 'nextMonth':
                    this.currentMonthView++;
                    if(this.currentMonthView > 11) {
                        this.currentYearView++;
                        this.currentMonthView = 0;
                    }
                    rebuildCalendar.call(this);
                break;
                case 'day':
                    this.element.value = formatDate(new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, e.target.innerHTML).getTime(), this.config);
                    this.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    documentClick: function(e) {
        if(e.target != this.element && e.target != this.calendar) {
            var parentNode = e.target.parentNode;
            if(parentNode != this.calender) {
                while(parentNode != this.calendar) {
                    parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                    if(parentNode == null) {
                        this.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function formatDate(milliseconds, config) {
    var formattedDate = '',
    dateObj = new Date(milliseconds),
    format = {
        d: function() {
            var day = format.j();
            return (day < 10) ? '0' + day : day;
        },
        D: function() {
            return config.weekdays[format.w()].substring(0, 3);
        },
        j: function() {
            return dateObj.getDate();
        },
        l: function() {
            return config.weekdays[format.w()];
        },
        S: function() {
            return config.suffix[format.j()] || config.defaultSuffix;
        },
        w: function() {
            return dateObj.getDay();
        },
        F: function() {
            return monthToStr(format.n(), true, config.months);
        },
        m: function() {
            var month = format.n() + 1;
            return (month < 10) ? '0' + month : month;
        },
        M: function() {
            return monthToStr(format.n(), false, config.months);
        },
        n: function() {
            return dateObj.getMonth();
        },
        Y: function() {
            return dateObj.getFullYear();
        },
        y: function() {
            return format.Y().toString().substring(2, 4);
        }
    },
    formatPieces = config.dateFormat.split('');

    foreach(formatPieces, function(formatPiece, index) {
        if(format[formatPiece] && formatPieces[index - 1] != '\\') {
            formattedDate += format[formatPiece]();
        } else {
            if(formatPiece != '\\') {
                formattedDate += formatPiece;
            }
        }
    });

    return formattedDate;
}

function foreach(items, callback) {
    var i = 0, x = items.length;
    for(i; i < x; i++) {
        if(callback(items[i], i) === false) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

function addEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
    if(element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    } else if(element.attachEvent) {
        var fixedCallback = function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault = (function(e) {
                return function() { e.returnValue = false; }
            })(e);
            e.stopPropagation = (function(e) {
                return function() { e.cancelBubble = true; }
            })(e);
            e.target = e.srcElement;
            callback.call(element, e);
        };
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventType, fixedCallback);
    }
}

function removeEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
    if(element.removeEventListener) {
        element.removeEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    } else if(element.detachEvent) {
        element.detachEvent('on' + eventType, callback);
    }
}

function buildNode(nodeName, attributes, content) {
    var element;

    if(!(nodeName in buildCache)) {
        buildCache[nodeName] = document.createElement(nodeName);
    }

    element = buildCache[nodeName].cloneNode(false);

    if(attributes != null) {
        for(var attribute in attributes) {
            element[attribute] = attributes[attribute];
        }
    }

    if(content != null) {
        if(typeof(content) == 'object') {
            element.appendChild(content);
        } else {
            element.innerHTML = content;
        }
    }

    return element;
}

function monthToStr(date, full, months) {
    return ((full == true) ? months[date] : ((months[date].length > 3) ? months[date].substring(0, 3) : months[date]));
}

function isToday(day, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    return day == date.current.day() && currentMonthView == date.current.month.integer() && currentYearView == date.current.year();
}

function buildWeekdays(weekdays) {
    var weekdayHtml = document.createDocumentFragment();
    foreach(weekdays, function(weekday) {
        weekdayHtml.appendChild(buildNode('th', {}, weekday.substring(0, 2)));
    });
    return weekdayHtml;
}

function rebuildCalendar() {
    while(this.calendarBody.hasChildNodes()){
        this.calendarBody.removeChild(this.calendarBody.lastChild);
    }

    var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
    numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);

    this.currentMonth.innerHTML = date.month.string(this.config.fullCurrentMonth, this.currentMonthView, this.config.months) + ' ' + this.currentYearView;
    this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
}

function buildCurrentMonth(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView, months) {
    return buildNode('span', { className: 'current-month' }, date.month.string(config.fullCurrentMonth, currentMonthView, months) + ' ' + currentYearView);
}

function buildMonths(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    var months = buildNode('div', { className: 'months' }),
    prevMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'prev-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'prevMonth' }, '&lt;')),
    nextMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'next-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'nextMonth' }, '&gt;'));

    months.appendChild(prevMonth);
    months.appendChild(nextMonth);

    return months;
}

function buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    var calendarBody = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    row = buildNode('tr'),
    dayCount = 0, i;

    /* print out previous month's "days" */
    for(i = 1; i <= firstOfMonth; i++) {
        row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
        dayCount++;
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
        /* if we have reached the end of a week, wrap to the next line */
        if(dayCount == 7) {
            calendarBody.appendChild(row);
            row = buildNode('tr');
            dayCount = 0;
        }

        var todayClassName = isToday(i, currentMonthView, currentYearView) ? { className: 'today' } : null;
        row.appendChild(buildNode('td', todayClassName, buildNode('span', { className: 'day' }, i)));

        dayCount++;
    }

    /* if we haven't finished at the end of the week, start writing out the "days" for the next month */
    for(i = 1; i <= (7 - dayCount); i++) {
        row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
    }

    calendarBody.appendChild(row);

    return calendarBody;
}

function buildCalendar() {
    var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
    numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView),
    self = this;

    var inputLeft = inputTop = 0,
    obj = this.element;

    if(obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            inputLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
            inputTop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }

    var calendarContainer = buildNode('div', { className: 'calendar' });
    calendarContainer.style.cssText = 'display: none; position: absolute; top: ' + (inputTop + this.element.offsetHeight) + 'px; left: ' + inputLeft + 'px; z-index: 100;';

    this.currentMonth = buildCurrentMonth(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView, this.config.months)
    var months = buildMonths(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);
    months.appendChild(this.currentMonth);

    var calendar = buildNode('table', null, buildNode('thead', null, buildNode('tr', { className: 'weekdays' }, buildWeekdays(this.config.weekdays))));
    this.calendarBody = buildNode('tbody');
    this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
    calendar.appendChild(this.calendarBody);

    calendarContainer.appendChild(months);
    calendarContainer.appendChild(calendar);

    document.body.appendChild(calendarContainer);

    addEvent(calendarContainer, 'click', function(e) { handlers.calendarClick.call(self, e); });

    return calendarContainer;
}

return function(elementId, userConfig) {
    var self = this;

    this.element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    this.config = {
        fullCurrentMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'F jS, Y',
        weekdays: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        suffix: { 1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd', 21: 'st', 22: 'nd', 23: 'rd', 31: 'st' },
        defaultSuffix: 'th'
    };
    this.currentYearView = date.current.year();
    this.currentMonthView = date.current.month.integer();

    if(userConfig) {
        for(var key in userConfig) {
            if(this.config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.config[key] = userConfig[key];
            }
        }
    }

    this.documentClick = function(e) { handlers.documentClick.call(self, e); }

    this.open = function(e) {
        addEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);

        foreach(datepickrs, function(datepickr) {
            if(datepickr != self) {
                datepickr.close();
            }
        });

        self.calendar.style.display = 'block';
    }

    this.close = function() {
        removeEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);
        self.calendar.style.display = 'none';
    }

    this.calendar = buildCalendar.call(this);

    datepickrs.push(this);

    if(this.element.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
        addEvent(this.element, 'focus', this.open);
    } else {
        addEvent(this.element, 'click', this.open);
    }
}
})();
```

I appreciate your help :)

-ShadowMinion

Comment: Why all this boilerplate when you can very easily get this done using readymade plugins ??

Comment: May be you can make a date object using `new Date`. This will give you current date. Thereafter you can compare your dates with this date for disabling them, so that they are non-selectable

Comment: Saurabh are you able to give me an example?

Comment: Yes why not..there are multiple date picker available. You can use `https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/` or `https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/`